# 301 ignoring dynamic url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

ok, first post on stackoverflow, here i go.

i'm strugling to write a 301 redirect for a migration of an old site.
The site uses dynamic url's and these don't seem to work.

old site: http://oldsite.com/index.php?actie=contact

new site: http://newsite.com/contact

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /index.php?actie=contact http://newsite.com/contact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirec` directive cannot match query string.

Use your rule like this in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^actie=contact$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://newsite.com/contact? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but how do i combine several redirects?
As soon as i add another, only the 1st one seems to work

Comment: What are other redirect examples you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string in a `Redirect`, you have to use mod_rewrite and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. (also note that `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive, and has nothing to do with the rewrite engine)

Options +FollowSymlinks

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^actie=contact(^|&)
RewriteRule ^index\.php http://newsite.com/contact? [L,R=301]
```

If you want to make it a general rule to match anything after the `actie=`, then:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^actie=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php http://newsite.com/%1? [L,R=301]
```